# how to update chart.js boundaries smoothly (without jumping and like time)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

how can I update chart.js boundaries smoothly and without jumping (like time)?

I used "type:time" but it changes my labels, I want my labels to be in current format:

[image]

code sandbox sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dream-6ck7w?file=/src/pages/Index.vue